# How to send Mails from localhost using gmail and SMTP Pro Magento

Tags: email, ce-1.9.0.1, smtp

I am using Magento version 1.9 on localhost. In project I want to send email on register. I have installed SMTP Pro. And configured my Gmail Account to send mail. But I am missing somewhere so I am failing to send mail.
Anybody know about it please let me know.

- Using magento 1.9 on localhost.
- Installed SMTP Pro from ASchroder.com
- Using Gmail Account to SMTP.

Comment: Are you sure your localhost is capable of sending emails? Do you have a SMTP server installed? Postfix, Qmail?

Comment: Using SMTP Pro with a configured GMail account bypasses the need for the localhost to send email (no exim, sendmail, qmail, postfix or other detritus) or have an SMTP server. It talks direct.

Comment: Thanks for support. My Issue is resolved.
Thanks once again.

Comment: how can you did, could you pls explain

Answer (score 1):

To send emails from localhost, take these steps:

- Download Magento SMTP Pro Extension by Ashley Schroder (free)
- Set up it on localhost
- Then configure Gmail as default.
  For detailed guide, you can look for it at [magento tutorial](http://www.mage-world.com/blog/lesson-3-how-to-set-up-sending-emails-on-localhost-for-magento.html)