# Magento 2: How to send emails from localhost?

Tags: magento2, email, magento-2.1, localhost, smtp

I'm working on a module which sends emails from admin panel on some action. I want to test these emails on localhost. How can I configure my Magento 2.1 settings or add `SMTP` so that sends emails over localhost?

Comment: Have installed SMTP Pro extension for it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send Mails from localhost using gmail and SMTP Pro Magento](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/28845/how-to-send-mails-from-localhost-using-gmail-and-smtp-pro-magento)

Comment: below solutins not working?

Comment: The above link is getting some error. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpnBG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpnBG.png)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/141526)

Comment: this is new repo https://github.com/emizentech/custom-smtp-magento2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If highest voted answer's repo doesn't show up than you can use below free extension by MagePlaza to send emails on xampp.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `SMTP` for this.
And for `SMTP` configuration you can use any extension.

https://github.com/emizentech/custom-smtp-magento2

From this extension you can configure your `SMTP` detail in admin and based on that you can send email from local system

Comment: i am getting this No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 after installation

Comment: can you help me please

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari ... take a look at https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp/issues/12

Comment: Unfortunately the repository in the answer has been the subject of a DMCA takedown and is no longer available.

Comment: The URL does is not valid anymore. That's why StackExchange encourages to put full answers here rather than URLs and links. Links get broken and content gets removed.

Comment: new repo https://github.com/emizentech/custom-smtp-magento2

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ssmtp. This can be configured to work with gmail.

In Gmail you need to configure your account to allow less secure apps.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

To install ssmtp with stock Ubuntu enter:

```
sudo apt-get install ssmtp
```

Then you need a basic setup for your `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf`, for example:

```
#
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=d.vader@gmail.com

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

AuthMethod=LOGIN
AuthUser=d.vader@gmail.com
AuthPass=Alderaan
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
rewriteDomain=gmail.com

# The full hostname
hostname=DeathStar

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
FromLineOverride=YES

root:d.vader@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

This will now enable you to have your emails work in Magento2 including for the newsletter send.

This approach also allows you to run a stock demo store on your localhost without any third party modules for SMTP delivery.

Configuration of your email sending can therefore be de-coupled from your Magento build making testing and deployment simpler.

Comment: Worked flawlessly. 