# How to send mail from magento2 in localhost

Tags: magento2

I need to sent mail from localhost but can't able to do.

Comment: it's possible only if you use xampp not wampp
open your php.ini file and set SMTP port and ip of your server

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141977/magento-2-how-to-send-emails-from-localhost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For send email from localhost use **SMTP** extension for Magento 2

Step to configure extension :

- Download from [Magepal Gmail smtp](https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app)
- Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- Go to `Store > Configuration > Advanced > System > SMTP configuration & settongs`
- You can send test mail from configuration after all configuration done.

That's all done!

Comment: Thanks for your response, It's works well

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2 provides an easy way to set custom SMTP to send emails from the localhost.

To configure it, go to **Stores** >> **Configuration** >> **DOTMAILER** >> **Transactional Emails** section, and set the following values:

- **Enabled** - Yes
- **Host** - {Your SMTP Host}
- **Username** - {Your Email Username}
- **Password** - {Your Email Password}
- **Port** - {SMTP Port Number}

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [MagePal Gmail SMTP](https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmail-smtp-app) to send the email.

And use [MailHog](https://github.com/mailhog/MailHog) if only need to test the mail in localhost

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu/Linux then following link will help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969783/phpubuntu-send-email-using-gmail-form-localhost/45125490#45125490

Follow these steps even i have configured it this way